# stop setInterval and if not work in react native function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the code below:

```js
contaTempo(){
  setInterval(() => this.setState({tempo: this.state.tempo+1}), 1000)
  if (this.state.tempo >= 5) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Sobre')
  }
}
```

The `setInterval` works correctly but the `if` doesn't work. Also, the timer neve stops. Any help?

Comment: You want to navigate to `'Sobre'` after 5 seconds, is that it?

Comment: @acdcjunior yes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `if` is running right away.

You want to place it inside the function passed to `setInterval`.

Also, you probably want to remove the timer as well, so call `clearInterval()` on the value returned by `setInterval`.

Furthermore, to prevent adding more than necessary to the `this.state.tempo`, move it to the `else` of the `if` statement.

Changed code would be like:

```js
contaTempo(){
  let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (this.state.tempo >= 5) {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Sobre')
    } else {
      this.setState({tempo: this.state.tempo+1});
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: its works, but if I navigate to other screen, the code not stop

Comment: how I stop the setInterval when I navigate to other screen? I try `componentWillUnmount() {clearInterval(myInterval);}` but its not work

Comment: In the updated code, you clear the interval before navigating to `Sobre`, didn't that work?

Comment: I have others buttons to navigate for others screens. example: I navigate to screen ('Test'), but after 5sec, the screen 'Sobre' is open automaticaly. Understand?

Comment: Entendi nao, pode falar em portugues, mesmo :P Aqui nos comentarios nao vai dar treta nao (quando eh em pergunta/resposta a galera apaga/edita).

Comment: Blz, vê só. tenho uma tela 'Inicio' com 4 botões pra outras telas. Nela, apliquei o seu código pra depois de 5 segundos abrir a tela 'Sobre'. Porém se eu trocar de tela, digamos que eu vá pra tela 'Teste' a contagem dos 5 segundos continua, e mesmo eu estando na tela 'Teste', a tela 'Sobre' é aberta. Como eu faço pra parar a contagem quando ir pra tela 'Teste'?

Comment: Aquele `clearInterval(myInterval);` para o timer. Será que não é alguém chamando o `contaTempo()` de novo?

Comment: consegui fazer funcionar sim, só não entendo porque ele não funciona no componentWillUnmount... tive que criar outra função pra parar o contador :/

Comment: "Ele" quem não funciona no componentWillUnmount?